# What would cause InternetExplorerMedium to work on one machine but not another?

Tags: uitableview, ms-access, vba

I have a VBA script in Access that logs onto a website and downloads some data, I built it using a laptop and use the code of

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorerMedium 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
Dim element As HTMLLinkElement
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
On Error GoTo Errorhandler
objIE.Visible = False
DoCmd.Hourglass (True) 'navigate IE to this web page
objIE.navigate www.google.com ' google just for example
```

Then it inputs the login info into the proper boxes and logs in.

Which works fine, however I installed this front end on another user's PC and it no longer works, it just opens the page but fills in no info.

However, if I change,

```
Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

to

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

then it works on their PC. But this change does not work on my laptop.

What would cause this issue and how could I standardize this so I can install on any windows machine without worry of this occurring.

Notes:
We are both on the company LAN, and both are running windows 10 Home.

Comment: Do you have the same internet security settings?

Comment: Thanks, that made me realize the error.
It was something incredibly simple, I just had to add the website I was accessing as a trusted site in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was something incredibly simple, I just had to add the website I was accessing as a trusted site in Internet Explorer.

Comment: So if it is a trusted site, you have to use InternetExplorerMedium, otherwise InternetExplorer is fine?

Comment: I am not for sure about that, I had trouble with InternetExplorer, it just refused to work without any real reason I could figure out. I literally went into IE and then to Settings, to set up a trusted site.